# Get the values of a checkbox field in node when evaluating in block condition plugin

Tags: plugins

I have a field that is a checkbox with multiple values... I'm trying to do an evaluation in a condition plugin where I'm checking against the checked values. For a boolean field, the syntax is:

```
$value = $this->getContextValue('node')->field_news_filter_menus->value;
```

Since field_news_filter_menus is a checkboxes field, I need to get the array of checked values.
These all return null:

```
$this->getContextValue('node')->field_news_filter_menus->list->values;
$this->getContextValue('node')->field_news_filter_menus->values;
$this->getContextValue('node')->field_news_filter_menus->list;
```

PHPstorm xdebug says the path is

```
$this->getContextValue('node')->field_news_filter_menus->list[0]->value;
```

But null is returned for that also.
I can see the values in xdebug that follow a path as

```
$this->getContextValue('node')->field_news_filter_menus->list[0]->values
```

and see an expected value, but that path also returns null.

What is the syntax for getting that array list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

The proper way to access field values is `$entity->get('my_field')->getValue()` in your case this will return an array like:

```
Array(
  0 => Array(
    'value' => 'value1'
  ),
  1 => Array(
    'value' => 'value2'
  ),
  2 => Array(
    'value' => 'value3'
  ),
  // And so on as many values your field has.
)
```

Also you can check if the field is empty by calling `$entity->get('my_field')->isEmpty()`. Calling only your field like `$entity->get('my_field')` will **NOT** return the field value but the field instance. Calling for an unexisting field will throw a runtime exception.

**UPDATE**

To check if the value exists you can either iterate over the array or do something like this

```
$arr = [
  0 => [
    'value' => 'value1',
  ],
  1 => [
    'value' => 'value2',
  ],
  2 => [
    'value' => 'value3',
  ],
];

$arr = array_map(function ($v) {
  return $v['value'];
}, $arr);

assert(in_array('value2', $arr, TRUE), 'Assert that contains value2');
assert(in_array('other', $arr, TRUE), 'Assert that contains other. This will fail');
```

You can try it [here](https://repl.it/@d70rr3s/arrayoperations).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly as it is returned. Thanks... I need to know if a value is in that array. So, is 'value2' in that array?

Comment: You are going to have to write a foreach and check the value that way.

Comment: Yeah foreach, array_map, array_reduce pick your flavor.